# Should we have a chess board feature implemented here at http://chess.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion

Should we have a chess board feature implemented here at http://chess.stackexchange.com?

Comment: This question is better suited for Meta, but as @user1583209 mentions it's a duplicate.